# I returned an array, but when I try to copy over that array NetBeans cannot find the symbol

Tags: java, arrays, methods

package program16;

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author buddysWorld
 */
public class Program16 
{
    public String[] myName(String firstName, String lastName) 
    {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter your first name:");
      firstName = in.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Enter your last name:");
      lastName = in.nextLine();
      String fullNameFunc[]= {firstName, lastName};
      return fullNameFunc;
   }
   public static void main(String []args) 
   {
      String firstName = "";
      String lastName = "";
      String[] fullNameMain = fullNameFunc.clone();
      System.out.println("Your name is " + fullNameMain[0] + " " + fullNameMain[1]);
   }
}
```

Here (String[] fullNameMain = fullNameFunc.clone();) it says "cannot find symbol, variable fullNameFunc, class Program16"
I have no other errors.

Comment: `fullNameFunc` is local to `myName`. You may be wanting to use the result of *calling* `myName`, on an instance of `Program16` that does not yet exist (or you mean it to be `static`, hard to say).

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `fullNameFunc` is defined inside method `myName` which means that it can only be defined in there because it's its scope.

However, since the variable `fullNameFunc` is the return value of the method `myName` you could replace

```java
fullNameFunc.clone();
```

by

```java
myName(firstName, lastName).clone();
```

---

Here is a full corrected version of your code where I also redefined the scopes of `firstName` and `lastName`

```java
public static String[] myName() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your first name:");
    String firstName = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter your last name:");
    String lastName = in.nextLine();
    return new String[]{firstName, lastName};
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] fullNameMain = myName().clone();
    System.out.println("Your name is " + fullNameMain[0] + " " + fullNameMain[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Program16 
{
    public static String[] myName(String firstName, String lastName) 
    {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter your first name:");
      firstName = in.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Enter your last name:");
      lastName = in.nextLine();
      String fullNameFunc[]= {firstName, lastName};
      return fullNameFunc;
   }
   public static void main(String []args) 
   {
      String firstName = "";
      String lastName = "";
      String[] fullNameFunc = myName(firstName, lastName);
      String[] fullNameMain = fullNameFunc.clone();
      System.out.println("Your name is " + fullNameMain[0] + " " + fullNameMain[1]);
   }
}
```

You need to make myName() method static. And you forgot to add "String[] fullNameFunc = myName(firstName, lastName);" line in main() method.